# Tableau huge if else condition calculation resulting in request size exceeds Parser limit of 1048500 bytes

Tags: tableau-api, teradata

I have a Tableau report on Teradata instance and used a large IF,ELSEIF..ELSE condition in one calculation field which basically operates on 2 fields after join on 3 tables.
Now I am unable to extend this condition any more due to Teradata limitation on request size:

> [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Request size exceeds Parser limit of 1048500 bytes.

Comment: If you have 1 megabyte of nested if/else, there is a design problem somewhere... You are doing it damn wrong. Better describe what you are *actually* trying to do.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: Not always, I had 600KB of nested CASEs automatically created (from a table) :-)

Comment: If the SQL is formatted there's a lot of unneeded white space. I don't know about Tableau, but there might be an option to remove this before submitting the query.

Comment: @dnoeth I can do it too, I just (strongly) suspect it's not the optimal way. Of course it has to be automatic. But doing automatically something wrong does not mean it's suddenly a good approach. I can get long if/else sequences when recoding variables for instance. Does not mean it's a good way of recoding.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: Of course, pats4u better describes his business question first.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: I am trying to put together stats on errors like stack trace, but need a shorter version of errors. ex: If CONTAINS([ERROR],'NullPointerException') THEN 'NullPointerException'. I know its not ideal & can't possibly cover every error, however If I can cover the top ones, that would suffice.

Comment: `IF` & `CONTAINS` are not part of Teradata SQL, Tableau must rewrite it (and might do it in a stupid/verbose way). You might be able to apply Regular Expressions to extract this info. Can you show some example data?